# Find supplier which supplies a product that others don't

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write an SQL query which selects the supplier based on the fact that it can supply a product other suppliers cannot.

I have 2 columns:
Supplier and Product

How would I select all the suppliers which supply at least 1 product which other suppliers do not supply?

I currently have:

```
SELECT incart.product, incart.supplier
FROM incart
WHERE incart.product 
HAVING count(incart.supplier)=1
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  i1.supplier
FROM incart i1
WHERE i1.product NOT IN(SELECT product 
                        FROM incart i2
                        WHERE i1.supplier <> i2.supplier);
```

For example, for the following sample data:

```
| PRODUCT | SUPPLIER |
|---------|----------|
|       1 |        a |
|       2 |        b |
|       3 |        b |
|       2 |        c |
|       3 |        c |
|       4 |        c |
```

It will select suppliers `a` and `c`, because supplier `a` supplies product 1 which others don't, and supplier `c` supplies product 4 which others don't.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/087e4/1)

Comment: I think a `GROUP BY` would make the output look cleaner ;) But it works!

Comment: @Ortix92 - You might need to use `DISTINCT` instead, if you are selecting only one column `supplier` then there is no need to use `GROUP BY`, also don't use `GROUP BY` without aggregate function, it works in some RDBMS like MySQL for example, but this is not the standard way to do so.